# I don't like neither of them. (does this mean? = I do like either of them)

Tags: grammar, sentence-meaning

> I don't like neither of them (do**n't**+**n**=positive meaning) = I do like either of them.

Can the sentence above be replaced by "I do like either of them(I at least like one of the two)." ?

Comment: That dosen't answer my question. My question is whether 'logically' the double negation makes a positive meaning and makes any senses in case of the 'posted' example sentence. I think 'Kate Bunting' or 'Fumble Fingers' could give their comments on this question.

Comment: You have a negative /don't like/, so, don't use neither. That would make a double negative.

Comment: It's a double negative. Some dialects of English use this. It means "I don't like either of them".  Don't try to use logic for this. There is none.

Comment: In my native language, double negation makes a positive meaning.

Comment: @BEBYGONES - yes, but this is dialect/colloquial English - not your language. Different languages have different rules, and English dialects frequently have non-standard grammar.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks for your explanation. I know 'not either' means 'total negation' and 'not both' means 'partial negation' and 'neither' means 'total negation' but just wanted to know if 'not' + 'neither' makes 'partial negation', just logically.

Comment: Generally in English when we encounter  non-standard double negatives, we understand them by basically ignoring one of the negatives.  For example "I ain't got no money" = "I haven't got any money".  "I never did nothing" = "I never did anything".  "I never saw nothing" = "I never saw anything".

Comment: Your title asks "Is this idiomatic or at least does this make sense?" If you actually want to ask "whether 'logically' the double negation makes a positive meaning", then I recommend you change the title.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question as a question? Right now, it's just a statement. In the title doesn't count.

Comment: "I do like either of them" is bad English. You can say, "I do like *one* of them."

Answer (score 3):

> I don’t like neither of them

is not idiomatic. English tends to avoid double negatives because they are hard to parse.

If you are talking about logic, you can use the artificial language known as the propositional calculus, where letters stand for statements and ~ stands for not.

Basic rules in propositional calculus are

~(p and q) is equivalent to -p or ~q, where the “or” is inclusive, and

~(~r) is equivalent to r.

So ~(~u and ~ v) is equivalent to ~(~u) or ~(~v), which is equivalent to u or v. Because the “or” is inclusive, u or v means u but not v, or v but not u, or both u and v, all of which can be subsumed under “at least one of u and v.”

In other words, English has the resources to express the concept **without** complicated logical reasoning.

If you want to study logic, learn the language of propositional calculus. But do not expect the natural language English to be modeled on the artificial language of propositional calculus.

EDIT: I see that there is a comment saying that your sentence is idiomatic with the reservation that the domain being considered involves dialects. That is true. But in received English, it is not acceptable.

Comment: +1 for squeezing some propositional calculus into ELL.

Comment: @tkp Propositional calculus is just another language.

Comment: Yup. As is predicate calculus, higher order logics, modal logics, and any number of others. Saussure would have us see pretty much everything we humans do as language, and Wittgenstein, the later at least, wouldn't disagree with him. Derrida and pals would crap over the whole lot, of course, but even he is "doing" language. In the end, perhaps it's *all* language, for some definition of the word. Nevertheless, I still give you kudos for managing to deploy some formalism into an ELL answer. 